# gvisMotionChart - Date format won't show as desired - "date.format="%m"

Tags: r, googlevis

I've data from 2014-01-01 to 2015-02-26.
And i want to show it within a MotionChart from googleVis package, with the timevar showing: months, instead of concreate date: "1/1/15".

I call the data like this:

```
Ikasa_Adwords <- read.csv("...Ikasa_Adwords.csv", 
                          header = T)


Ikasa_Adwords$date <- as.Date(Ikasa_Adwords$date)
```

Then apply this to generate the MotionChart:

```
M <- gvisMotionChart(Ikasa_Adwords, idvar="campaign", timevar="date",
                      xvar="ad.cost",yvar="impressions", date.format="%m")

plot(M)
```

Image:

[image]

As you see: I've "date.format="%m" but, still date is shonw as "1/1/15". Why?

My data (first rows):

```
      date             campaign         sessions    ad.cost ad.clicks   impressions
1   2014-01-01  Brand Search - Motos      0           1.35      7        21
2   2014-01-01  Brand Search - Autos      2           0.28      1        6
3   2014-01-01  Brand Search - Aviones    21          3.76      20       187
4   2014-01-01  Brand Search - Barcos     7           1.21      3        10
5   2014-01-01  Brand Search - Camiones   9           1.37      6        33
```

OutPut from str() function:

```
 str(Ikasa_Adwords)
'data.frame':   7878 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ date       : Date, format: "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" ...
 $ campaign   : Factor w/ 45 levels "(not set)","Brand Search - Motos,..: 2 3 5 7 9 10 12 14 16 17 ...
 $ sessions   : int  0 2 21 7 9 14 0 9 11 5 ...
 $ ad.cost    : num  1.35 0.28 3.76 1.21 1.37 ...
 $ ad.clicks  : int  7 1 20 3 6 9 1 9 7 4 ...
 $ impressions: int  21 6 187 10 33 84 9 105 47 25 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This example a bit better actually and it may help you.

```
myStateSettings <-'
{"xZoomedDataMin":1199145600000,"colorOption":"2",
"duration":{"timeUnit":"M","multiplier":1},"yLambda":1,
"yAxisOption":"4","sizeOption":"_UNISIZE",
"iconKeySettings":[],"xLambda":1,"nonSelectedAlpha":0,
"xZoomedDataMax":1262304000000,"iconType":"LINE",
"dimensions":{"iconDimensions":["dim0"]},
"showTrails":false,"uniColorForNonSelected":false,
"xAxisOption":"_TIME","orderedByX":false,"playDuration":15000,
"xZoomedIn":false,"time":"2010","yZoomedDataMin":0,
"yZoomedIn":false,"orderedByY":false,"yZoomedDataMax":100}
'
M6a <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, "Fruit", "Year",
                       options=list(state=myStateSettings))
plot(M6a)
```

See the difference when you change `"timeUnit":"M"` to `"timeUnit":"Y"`; this may help.